# Proving if a^2 -b^2 is even, a-b is also even

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

As stated in title I am having trouble proving this.  I have been trying to use a proof by contradiction where I assume A^2-B^2 is even and A - B is odd and show how that is untrue.  Unfortunately I can't seem to figure this out.

I have tried setting the even expression equal to 2x (implying even) and the odd to 2y+1 and solving.  Unfortunately I got stuck with this.

Any solution using any method would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll probably get better answers on the Math SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If a-b is odd, can a+b be even? Think about it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Comment: The context behind this is I need to make sure this was true for an algorithm I had to write.  I guess it is off-topic though because of the way I presented the problem.  My apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint factorize `A^2-B^2 = (A - B) (A + B)`.

This implies that if `A^2-B^2` is even then `(A - B) (A + B)` is even. If `A-B` is odd then...

Comment: @JavaBob, I made an edit, I don't see how I could make this more clear without giving a full solution.

Comment: I understand after you made the edit. Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully you can now see how this leads to the contradiction. If you wanted a different proof method that wasn't proof-by-contradiction you might want to make use of the fact that even numbers are `2n` and odd numbers are `2n+1` where `n` is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try four possibilities: both A and B are even, A is odd and B even, B is even and A odd, and both A and B are odd.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question.  A^2-B^2 is assumed even, and I am trying to prove that A- B is also even. While I can't explain it this is always the case so it should be provable

Comment: @JavaBob Look at those four choices, and see which will make A^2-B^2 even.  Based on that, can you say whether A-B is even?

Answer (score 0):

A^2-B^2 = (A+B)(A-B)=(C+2B)C

where C=A-B. But C and (C+2B) have the same parity. Then, if A^2-B^2 is even, so is C

Answer (score 0):

We just take a look at each case:

- *If a and b are both even, then say a=2n, b=2m, then a-b is even and a²-b²=4n²-4m²=4(n²-m²) therefore a²-b² is also even (it can be divided by 4).
- If a is even and b is odd, then say a=2n, b=2m+1, then a²-b² is odd and a²-b²=4n²-4m²+4m-1=4(n²-m²+m)-1 which is and odd number.
- If a is odd and b is even then a-b is odd, then let a=2n+1, b=2m, then a²-b²=4n²-4n+4m²+1=4(n²-n+m)+1 which is an odd number.ç
- Lastly, if both are odd, then let a=2n+1, b=2m+1. a-b is an even number as 2n+1-2m-1=2(n-m) (even). a²-b² is also even, as the 1s remaining cancell each other: a²-b²=4n²-4n+1-4m²+4m-1=4(n²-m²-n+m) is an even number.

What this proves is that, in all cases where a²-b² is even (when both a and b are either odd or even), then a-b must be also even. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off topic questions.